# Digitalocean Strapi uploading images error

Tags: digital-ocean, strapi

recently, I was deploying a backend in strapi(v3.6.8) on digitalocean (Running on 1 CPU + 1 GB + 10 GB Disk Droplets) following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ho7nLkXmaKE&list=WL&index=51&ab_channel=Strapi

Before the deploy, everything was working fine, however currently, when uploading multiple img to media-library in strapi, after a long loading time, the image icon turns red and errors occur as shown in the screenshot below. After clicking on anything the error invalid credentials appears, and after refreshing the page the whole strapi restarts, deleting all data and the admin account.

When I tried to add the same img for the second time the invalid credentials signature popped up and everything repeated as with the first error

When I add the same img one at a time I haven't encountered any error so far, but I have no idea what to do in case of error with multiple img.

[first upload error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND7Oi.png)
[second upload error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnlwH.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to follow this guide, https://github.com/shorwood/strapi-provider-upload-do. Although may not seem desirable it is necessary. Otherwise ever time you deploy, the content will be erased/overwritten by the new instance created from DigitalOcean.

You'll need to use a DigitalOcean Space to accommodate your assets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).